# Change multi-statement Table Valued Function (TVF) to inline TVF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Using SQLServer 2008.

Example multi-statement TVF :

```
CREATE TABLE DBO.DECTEST (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
V1 DECIMAL(18,6) NOT NULL, V2 DECIMAL(18,6) NOT NULL)

INSERT DECTEST VALUES (1, 23.1234, 25.22)

GO

DROP FUNCTION DBO.F_DECTEST1
GO
CREATE FUNCTION DBO.F_DECTEST1
(
@ID INT
)
RETURNS @RESULT TABLE
(   
    V1 DECIMAL(18,6),
    V2 DECIMAL(18,6)
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @V1 DECIMAL (18,6)
    DECLARE @V2 DECIMAL(18,6)
    SELECT @V1 = V1, @V2 = V2 FROM DBO.DECTEST WHERE ID = @ID

    INSERT @RESULT (V1, V2) VALUES (ISNULL(@V1, 0), ISNULL(@V2, 0))
    RETURN
END
GO
```

I want to change this to an inline TVF (for performance reasons). Note that one row is always returned in the result set - even if a non existent ID is passed. Is there a clean way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know if this is any better , but you can give this a try...

```
CREATE FUNCTION DBO.F_DECTEST1 
( 
@ID INT 
) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS  
RETURN
(
   SELECT V1, V2 FROM DBO.DECTEST WHERE ID = @ID 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT NULL AS V1, NULL AS V2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM DBO.DECTEST WHERE ID = @ID)
)
```

Also, why not go with a stored proc with output parameters? Since ID is unique and you need to return only one row.

Comment: we want a TVF so we can use CROSS APPLY with it. I was afraid the inline version was going to look fairly ugly, but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still interested, this is what I was after (Note that I should have really made columns V1 and V2 NULL-able in my original example to more reflect what I was after) :

```
CREATE FUNCTION DBO.F_DECTEST1
(
@ID INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
(
    SELECT ISNULL(w.V1, 0) AS V1 , ISNULL(w.V2, 0) AS V2
    FROM 
    (SELECT @ID AS ID) s 
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT V1, V2 FROM DBO.DECTEST WHERE ID = s.ID
    ) w
)
```